# How to use group_concat in inside IN() function?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ui.* 
FROM users_table as ui 
WHERE ui.id 
IN 
(
SELECT Group_concat
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE(ac.user_id,',,','-'),',',''),'-',',')) AS au_users 
FROM email_access as uu 
LEFT JOIN bill_authorizationcodes AS ac 
ON ac.customer_id = uu.cust_id 
WHERE uu.user_id = 2 
AND ac.user_id !=""
)
```

Its not selected all the id details...
its selecting first id only....

Comment: did you check his @Lorenz Meyer answer

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong approach. In does not expect a string with comma separated values, but a list of values. Just use

```
SELECT ui.* FROM users_table as ui 
WHERE ui.id IN (
    SELECT ac.user_id 
    FROM email_access as uu 
    LEFT JOIN bill_authorizationcodes AS ac ON ac.customer_id = uu.cust_id 
    WHERE uu.user_id = 2 AND ac.user_id !="")
```